Two different resolutions of a three fold
Let $X\subset \mathbb{A}^4_\mathbb{C}$ be a three fold defined by the equation $xy-zw=0$
This variety has a singularity at origin of $\mathbb{A}^4_\mathbb{C}$
If we blow up this three fold in two ways i.e by the ideals $(x,z)$ and $(y,z)$, we can get two resolutions $Y_0\rightarrow X,Y_1\rightarrow X$ with exceptional curves $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$
How can I prove $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ are not isomorphic over $X$.
I would like to prove this claim in order to prove $X$ has no minimal resolution.

The strict transform of the plane $x = z = 0$ in one of the resolutions is still a plane, and in the other it is isomorphic to the blowup of the plane.

Thanks.  I would like to ask you a one more question.

Why are  these blow up resolutions? Even if we restrict these maps to the complement of the fiber of singular locus , we cannot  get bijection on to it's image

This is a computation. Over the complement of the singularity, the blowup center is a Cartier divisor, so the blowup is the identity.

Thanks. I understand why these blowup are resolutions.
How to show this three fold has no minimal resolution by using these fact.

@George: for $i=0,1$, if $Y_i \rightarrow Z \rightarrow X$ is a factorisation with $Z$ smooth then $Y_i \rightarrow Z$ must be an isomorphism over $X$. Since $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ are not isomorphic over $X$, this means that the two morphisms $Y_i \rightarrow X$ cannot both factor through a morphism $Z \rightarrow X$ for some smooth $Z$.

Is it obvious that $Y_i\rightarrow Z$ must be isomorphism?
Could you tell me why?

It is easy to see that the Picard group of $Y_i$ has rank 1; therefore the morphism $Y_i \to X$ has no factorizations into a composition of two nontrivial projective morphisms.
